# WARNING: Deprecated property "<StringProperty name=text>" of object "<__main__.Tab >object at " was accessed, it will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to add a graph into a tab in KivyMD, this is the warning which comes up and the graph is not showing on the interface. this is the full error that I am receiving from the code:

[WARNING] Deprecated property "" of object "<**main**.Tab object at 0x0000011807CA3040>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [1, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8]

plt.plot(x, y)
y_label = 'performance'


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
     graph = StringProperty()


class StatsScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StatsScreen, self).__init__()
        self.graph = self.ids.Last_graph
        self.graph.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```

and here is the kivymd code for the screen:

```
<StatsScreen>
name: 'stats_interface'
MDFloatLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light

    MDLabel:
        id: heading_label
        text: 'Statistics'
        size_hint: (0.75, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5 , 'y':0.90}
        bold: True
        halign: 'center'

    MDTabs:
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.53
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5 , 'y':0.4 }
        tab_display_mode: 'text'
        Tab:
            name: 'Last Session'
            text: 'Last Session'
            FloatLayout:
                id: Last_graph
        Tab:
            name: 'Progress Graph'
            text: 'Progress Graph'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.39}
        md_bg_color: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
        line_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        radius: [15, ]

        MDLabel:
            id: goal_grade_label
            text: 'Goal Grade: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.8}
            bold: True

        MDLabel:
            id: current_grade_label
            text: 'Current Grade: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.5}
            bold: True

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.28}
        md_bg_color: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
        line_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        radius: [18, ]

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Last session analysis: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.8}
            bold: True

        MDLabel:
            id: percentage_label
            text: 'Percentage: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.6}

        MDLabel:
            id: grade_label
            text: 'Grade: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.4}

        MDLabel:
            id: marks_label
            text: 'Total Marks: '
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05 , 'center_y':0.2}

    MDTextButton:
        text: 'Return'
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.05)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.02}
        bold: True

    MDTextButton:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.05)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.475, 'y': 0.02}
        bold: True

    MDTextButton:
        text: 'Topics'
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.05)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.85, 'y': 0.02}
        bold: True

<Tab>:
    text: 'testing'
    FloatLayout:
    id: test_id
```

is there any way to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's not an `Error`, but rather a `Warning`, and if you read the content of the message, it is actually pretty clear that you are accessing a property of the `Tab` class that is classified as `deprecated`, which will then soon be removed entirely, though in this case it's a bit weird, since apparently it is trying to access a property named `""`. Don't worry, that warning text should go away when future versions of Kivy are released, but while you wait, you can hide these warning messages simply by adding in these lines of code:

```python
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("kivy", "log_level", "error")
Config.write()
```

Comment: thank you this fixed the warning however the graph is still not output into the tab. when I run the code the tabs are both blank. is there any way to fix this or do I have to add separate code to output it onto the tab.

Comment: Which widget are you referring to as your "graph" exactly, though?

Comment: I am adding a widget into the floatlayout in the first tab. when I looked at ways to have graphs on the screen this was the way which was used. I am very new to kivy so I mostly use the documentation and tutorials for this project.  is there any other way to add the graph into the floatlayout in the first tab or is there an issue with the id which I used to reference the specific place which I wanted to add the graph?